# Help! Can't Login - Accidently set Omega content zone to not display in content section

Tags: users, theming

mysite.com/user/login can't display the login form because I accidently set my content zone to not display. Is there a way to reverse this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a one-time login link.

```
drush uli
```

Comment: And here's a guide how to reset without drush if you don't have that installed: http://randyfay.com/content/resetting-drupal-passwords-drupal-7-drush-or-without